# 403 Error after upgrading passenger (for nginx) is keeping me up at night...where did I go wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I think I've read every question and answer on SO related to passenger/nginx and 403 errors, but none have lead me to a solution, so here I go...

I had Nginx (1.0.6) with Passenger (3.0.9) running beautifully for a rails app for many, many months with no real issues. Tonight I decided to upgrade from Passenger v3.0.9 to v3.0.12 to take advantage of a new feature. After running the install according to the provided instructions (using RVM), I went to the URL served by my rails app and got the dreaded 403 error. The nginx log file first had me thinking it was a permissions error:

```
 directory index of "/home/SimfoUsers/public/" is forbidden, client: , server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: ""
```

But after checking every possible permission, I no longer think that is the issue. I think the problem is actually that passenger is somehow not actually running, and the page is being served as a "normal" webpage by nginx. This is supported by the fact that if I add an index.html file to my rails public directory (/home/SimfoUsers/public/), nginx serves up this file as one would expect. Also, if I run passenger-memory-stats, ZERO passenger processes are running. Shouldn't nginx automatically spawn passenger processes whenever needed, or am I completely missing something here?

Here are the relevant parts of my nginx.conf file:

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@Simfo/gems/passenger-3.0.12;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290@Simfo/ruby;
    ...

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  simfo.info www.simfo.info;
        root         /home/SimfoUsers/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

Basically the only thing that I changed from my previously working config file is to update the passenger_root and passenger_ruby directives to reflect the new version of passenger (3.0.12). So if this is a config file issue, I'm really at a loss to understand it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether to just delete this question, or leave it in case it can save someone else the same frustration. This definitely is a face palm moment...

In desperation, I finally rebooted the server. After that, everything worked fine. It seems that at some point the passenger-related processes died and were not re-spawned automatically. One would think that after a fresh installation and reboot of nginx, passenger would be restarted, but apparentally this is not the case. My only advice to anyone having a similar problem is to issue a `ps aux | grep passenger` (or tasklist on Windows?). You should see one or two processes related to passenger. If not, then something strange is going on, and a reboot might help you as well.

Comment: But what if a reboot does NOT restart those passenger processes?

Comment: Then the root cause is likely something different than what I had. If you provide more details on the problems you are having, I (or others) can try to help you out.

Comment: I ended up changing passenger versions and re-running `passenger_install_nginx_module` to fix it. In retrospect I probably could've gone with just reinstalling the nginx module and not meddling with passenger versions.

Comment: Ok, well, glad to hear you got the problems fixed!